# Cookie lasting past their expires time?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following code that is supposed to limit the user's session to 30 minutes. For some reason we are seeing a small number of session that last for more that 30 minutes. Sometimes they last for days. Also this isn't tied to one browser as we are seeing users with Chrome, IE, Firefox, and mobile browser having this issue.

```
var domain = tld.getDomain(location.hostname);
var sessionTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1800000);
cookie.set("session", JSON.stringify(sessionData), {
    expires: sessionTime,
    path: "/",
    domain: domain
});
```

Is it possible for the session to persist after it should be expired? On page load I pull a UID from the session cookie and update the expires time. If there is no UID in the cookie, I create a new cookie.

Screenshot of the cookie's expire time in Chrome console. 
http://screencast.com/t/eJKeMlp0

I am using this cookie library.
https://github.com/js-coder https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js

And I'm using this library to determine the top level domain
https://github.com/oncletom/tld.js

Comment: One reason might simply be the client’s time being off (although if for several days, that must be some weird users).

Comment: even if the user clock was offset, presumably it still increments 60 seconds every min...

Comment: do you need  tld.getDomain, what's wrong with just document.domain or  location.hostname ? also, showing the rest of the code or a fiddle would help solicit answers.

Comment: @dandavis This code runs on international sites that have strange top level domains like, com.br. So for ex, sub.domain.site.com.br should save cookies to site.com.br, but without a library that knows all the tld, I cannot know if "com" is the sub domain, or part of the top level domain. 

I'll work on creating a example fiddle.

Comment: you don't need to know what part "com" is, and if your method produces something besides document.domain, the cookie might not reliably work and could be altered from a different sub site in an unpredictable manner.

Comment: @dandavis This cookie and code is shared between subdomains. I want one cookie per domain, not subdomain. document.domain gives you the subdomain if there is one.